# Session for entity Model not found in Dapper.Extensions.Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am using Dapper.Extensions.Linq . 
I have belowe Class to set its Configuration :

```
  public class Container
{
    Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer _container;
    public Container()
    {
        _container = new Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer();
    }


    public void RunBeforeAnyTests()
    {
        //_container = new Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer();

        DapperConfiguration
            .Use()
            .UseClassMapper(typeof(AutoClassMapper<>))
            .UseContainer<Dapper.Extensions.Linq.CastleWindsor.ContainerForWindsor>(c => c.UseExisting(_container))
            .UseSqlDialect(new SqlServerDialect())

            .WithDefaultConnectionStringNamed("con")
            .Build();


    }


    public void getTest()
    {

     var service=   _container.Resolve<IRepository<Person>>();
        var person = new Person { Id = 22, FirstName = "Foo", LastName = "Bar", DateCreated = DateTime.Now };
        service.Insert(person);// throw exception

    }
}
```

when I want to Insert a Person I've got this Error :

> Session for entity Person not found

there is nothing more information than this in its `Documentation` on GitHub And I dont know how Can I solve this .

**Update** :
My model is :

```
  public class Person : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are connecting to a database : .WithDefaultConnectionStringNamed("con").  Does the database have a table called "Person"?

Comment: @jdweng yes It has `dbo.Person` Table

Comment: @jdweng Please see the new Update

Comment: @jdweng I found it , I should use `.FromAssemblyContaining(typeof(Person))` . Now it works fine